# Analytic Solution for Second-Order Nonlinear PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, physics, fourier-transform

Consider the following partial differential equation,
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{k}\ln\left(1+e^{k\alpha\nabla^{2}\rho}\right)-\alpha\nabla^{2}\rho.
\end{equation}

Assuming a one dimensional system, we may set $\nabla^{2}\rho$ to $\frac{\partial^{2}\rho}{\partial x^{2}}$. Separation of variables doesn't seem to apply here. However, a Fourier transform yields

\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
\frac{d}{dt}\hat{p}=\frac{1}{k}\ln\left(1+e^{-k\alpha\omega^{2}\hat{p}}\right)+\alpha\omega^{2}\hat{p},
\end{equation}

such that

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathcal{F}\left(\rho\left(x,t\right)\right)&=\hat{\rho}\left(\omega,t\right),\\
\mathcal{F}\left(\rho_{\times}\right)&=i\omega\hat{\rho}\left(\omega,t\right),\\
\mathcal{F}\left(\rho_{\times\times}\right)&=-\omega^{2}\hat{\rho}\left(\omega,t\right),
\end{split}
\end{equation}

for the system in eq. $1$ denoted by $\rho_{t}=\frac{1}{k}\ln\left(1+e^{k\alpha\rho_{\times\times}}\right)-\alpha\rho_{\times\times}$. How could one solve eq. $2$ or use another method for eq. $1$? I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Are you certain about the Fourier transform of the term $\ln(1+e^{\dots})$?

Comment: No, that's my one reservation about the working. The PDE in eq. $1$ is derived from the heat equation (this almost acts opposite to it – i.e for large $k$, eq. $1$ approaches $\frac{\left|\alpha\nabla^{2}\rho\right|-\alpha\nabla^{2}\rho}{2}$). I am trying to solve it similarly to the heat equation, but I am finding it substantially more complicated with that log term.

Comment: Okay. I think (2) is incorrect then. Typically we take the Fourier transform of the whole equation, in which case we get a term like $\mathcal{F}(\ln(1+e^{\dots}))$, *or* replace each term with its Fourier integral $\rho(x) \to \int e^{iwx}\tilde{\rho}(w)$, and I don't see how either of those leads to eq. (2). Do you have reason to believe a 'nice' solution exists for (1)?

Comment: The system is theoretical, so it would be brilliant if a nice solution exists (but there is no guarantee). Numerically, it appears to hold (i.e modelling for discrete values of time $t\in\left(1,5\right)$ in MATLAB yields a correct path).

Comment: An exact closed form is extraordinarily unlikely. Even considering the steady state, we cannot solve for $\nabla^2 \rho$

Comment: What about when removing the $k$ term to produce $\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}=\frac{\left|\alpha\nabla^{2}\rho\right|-\alpha\nabla^{2}\rho}{2}$? RHS may be written as a piecewise function and I think a closed form could be found.

Comment: Previous comment may be solved simply by separating variables if we assume the form $\rho\left(x,t\right)=\mathcal{X}\left(x\right)\mathcal{T}\left(t\right)$: $\mathcal{T}\left(t\right)=t_{0}e^{\lambda^{2}\alpha t}$ and $\mathcal{X}\left(x\right)=A\sin\lambda x+B\cos\lambda x$ for all $\rho\left(x,t\right)\geq 0$, otherwise $\rho\left(x,t\right)=0$. It's unfortunate that a closed form can't be found for the original system (when not simplified). Been looking at the Feynman-Kac formula as a possibility for resolving this, but the log term continues to be the issue.

Comment: What are your initial and boundary conditions?

Comment: My previous solution was general. When specifying boundary conditions, I prefer dealing with the functional form (a Fourier transform works here). Let, $\rho\left(x,0\right)=f(x)$ and $f(x)$ denote $e^{-\ln^2 x}$. A solution may be written as $\rho(x,t)=2\alpha\sqrt{\pi t}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\left(x-y\right)^{2}}{4\alpha^{2}t}-\ln^{2}x}dy$.

Comment: I get $2\pi\alpha^{2}t\cdot e^{-\ln^{2}\left(x\right)}\left(1-\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{2\alpha\sqrt{t}}\right)\right)$ when solving the integral, but I think this is wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: I meant: what are your initial and boundary conditions for (1)? The problem is the integral is not correct: You need $\ln^2(y)$ not $\ln^2(x)$. Are you certain that your solution satisfies the simplified differential equation (from some comments ago) both when $\rho''<0$ and when $\rho''>0$? You only get the diffusion equation in one of those cases. Also, you should probably edit your attempts into your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in comments by simplifying the problem as a variant of the heat equation. However, any new thoughts on the original nonlinear PDE are welcome.